# How to move a directory from home to usr?

Tags: linux, fedora

I'm really new to linux and this might be a trivial question, but I'm having trouble moving a folder from my home directory to another directory in usr. I'm using this command: `sudo mv /home/koba/Downloads/Linux_PPDs_KSL8_4/PPD's_KSL_8.4/Italian /usr/share/cups/model/Kyocera` and it just blankly stares at me, it doesn't throw erros, nothing, it just goes `>` until I ctr+C out of it. Pls help. I'm using Fedora workstation 38 with the Gnome DE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It stares at you because your command has an unfinished *quoted* string, which starts at the `'` in `PPD's` but doesn't end anywhere. The `>` prompt (PS2) is usually shown when shell is assuming you're going to add more text and waiting for the closing `'` or `"`.

In your case, the `'` wasn't *meant* to be a shell quote character but rather a literal character, so it needs to be either a) escaped using a `\` prefix, or b) actually quoted using `"..."` – both the same things as you would do with spaces and other special characters within a file name.

```
mv /home/whatever/PPD\'s/Italian /usr/share/wherever

mv "/home/whatever/PPD's/Italian" /usr/share/wherever

mv /home/whatever/"PPD's"/Italian /usr/share/wherever
```

Note that a PPD is often not enough – it usually also references a "filter" program that needs to be in the right place for CUPS to execute.

On the other hand, for Kyocera you could probably just use the generic PCL6 (PCL-XL) or even PCL5e drivers; sometimes they work better than the Kyocera-specific ones.

Comment: Thank you, that solved it. I'll also look into what you suggested for Kyocera drivers, thanks for helping.